# Entity framework code first - violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql, ef-code-first

I have an ASP.NET application with code first Entity Framework approach. In one of my models (Product) I have following code:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
public bool IsConfirmet { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
```

And Owner class looks like this:

```
[Key]
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Address { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string Login { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

And later when I try to add product:

```
public static int AddProduct(Product product)
{
    db.Products.Add(product);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I got a message:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Owners'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Owners'. The duplicate key value is ([...]). The statement has been terminated.

I also get this message when I try to delete product.

```
public static void RemoveProducts()
{
    List<Product> products = db.Products.Where(p => p.IsConfirmed == false).ToList();

    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - product.AddedDate).TotalMinutes > 10)
        {
            db.Products.Remove(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This error occurs at db.SaveChanges() line. Which is strange for me becouse I thought it concerns adding operation.

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` means data type  `Guid`, not `unique key`

Comment: Of course you're right. I don't know how could I forget that. I'm going to rewrite my question becouse I have a problem with adding products into my database and I have no idea why.

Comment: Have you assigned a correct `Owner` to your `Product` before calling `AddProduct`?

Comment: Yes. It's a correct OwnerId. There is one difference - in database Guid is written in capital letters whereas in C# there are small letters. But the first product was added properly so it can't be a problem.

Comment: The error message indicates an attempt to insert a record in Owners table. The code you showed is adding a product. My point was to check the Owner property of that product - looks like EF is thinking it a new Owner entity. Is this a one to many relationship?

Comment: In my DbContext class I have following code: modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasRequired<Owner>(p => p.Owner).WithMany(p => p.Products).HasForeignKey(p => p.OwnerId); so I guess I have one to many relationship.

Comment: Something is wrong with the Owner property of the product passed to the function or the db context. I've tried your entity model and it works (in console application). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like I found what causes a problem. In my Product class OwnerId was correct but Owner field corresponding to OwnerId was empty. With correct Owner assigned to Owner field it works fine.

Comment: You welcome. That's what I meant from the beginning. You can avoid such problems by removing explicit xxxId properties and just use navigation properties. Like in your `Product` removing `OwnerId` property and `ForeignKey` attribute, and changing the configuration code to `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasRequired(p => p.Owner).WithMany(o => o.Products).Map(a => a.MapKey("OwnerId"));`. Anyway, problem solved, we are all good :-)

Comment: This is a great solution. I didn't know I can do that. Thank you very much.